# How do coinjoin and sharedcoin work? How to make it make it hard to pinpoint bitcoin sender wallet

Tags: wallet, privacy, coinjoin

I would like to implement a way for bitcoin transactions to be untraceable. EX. user1 on my site wants to send bitcoins to user2. How would I go about mixing the coins so user2 doesn't get user1's sent from address.

All open source bitcoin washers are javascript or python or something, I need to do this on my server and prefer not to use javascript on user end like SharedCoin.com does.

Would I be fine just sending the coins through 50 or so addresses with the values of the coins jumbled (I mean jumbled like, if user1 sents 1 btc, before the bitcoins get to user2 wallet, the coins would pass through the 50 or so btc addresses in mixed values, not just 1btc, but like 0.23 and 0.77 sent to two different addresses and then like 0.02 and 0.21 goto 1 address and 0.75 and 0.02 goes to another and it just continues to split more from their?)

I am aware of darkcoin, and that these bitcoin washers can be traced back, but this is something I need for bitcoin.

Thanks for any help at all.

Comment: For example, any idea on how these services work: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mixing_service I don't think they wait for new users to deposit bitcoins to reimburse people wanting washed coins (like a ponzi scheme lol) with coins that can't be traced back to an address or in the bitcoin washers eyes, fresh coins.

Comment: Why'd you make two questions? http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/30512/best-way-to-anonymize-bitcoin-transactions